# GWT codeserver parameter

Tags: gwt

i've encountered an issue on `GWT codeserver parameter` in a simple scenario below,

Project structure

```
myapp
+src
++mypkg
---MainWindow.gwt.xml
---NextWindow.gwt.xml
+++client
----MainWindow.java
----NextWindow.java
+war
--MainWindow.html
--NextWindow.html
```

MainWindow.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='mainwindow'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <entry-point class='mypkg.client.Mainwindow'/>
  <source path='client'/>
</module>
```

MainWindow.java

```
package mypkg.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

public class MainWindow implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Button button = new Button("NextWindow!");
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.open("/NextWindow.html", null, null);
            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(button);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.html

```
<!doctype html>      
<html>
<head>
<title>MainWindow</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="mainwindow/mainwindow.nocache.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>
    <h1>Hi, MainWindow!</h1>   
</body>
</html>
```

NextWindow.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='nextwindow'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <entry-point class='mypkg.client.NextWindow'/>
  <source path='client'/>
</module>
```

NextWindow.java

```
package mypkg.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

public class NextWindow implements EntryPoint {    
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get().add(new Label("Hi, NewLabel!"));
    }
}
```

NextWindow.html

```
<!doctype html>      
<html>
<head>
<title>NextWindow</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="nextwindow/nextwindow.nocache.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>
    <h1>Hi, NextWindow!</h1>   
</body>
</html>
```

On `Devmode` launch the compiled myapp from the link,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MainWindow.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

Click on button "NextWindow" then `GWT browser plugin` pops up a complaint window,

```
Module NextWindow need be (re)compiled!
```

Confirm it then a new browser window is open from the link on `Prodmode`,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/NextWindow.html
```

instead of the desired link on `Devmode`,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/NextWindow.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

Consequently it displays only,

```
Hi, NextWindow!
```

But the very anticipated content below doesn't show up,

```
Hi, NewLabel!
```

If we trail `GWT codeserver parameter` `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` to the source code, the problem could be solved by sacrificing the consistency on `source level` between `Devmode` and `Prodmode`.

What are the preferable solutions indeed?

Comment: you can check whether you are running in Production mode or in Development mode.  Depending on that you append the code server parameter.  You can check the mode by using GWT.isProdMode().

Comment: Thanks, `@MarioP` gave the same answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if(GWT.isProdMode())` to check for Prodmode and Devmode, and trail the parameter if it is devmode.

That doesn't affect production mode - the gwt compiler is smart enough to just ignore devmode-code, so the devmode-block never makes it into the compiled javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need. Is there any "official" reference to your statement - "the gwt compiler is smart enough to just ignore devmode-code".

Comment: Given that `GWT.isProdMode()` is hard-coded to return `true` in prod-mode, the GWT compiler will optimize out unreachable code, e.g. content of a `if (!GWT.isProdMode()) { … }`. This is part of the _standard_ optimizations done by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, concise but convincing.